# How many ways of a football score happening?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How many different ways are there for a football match to finish 3-3, and, generally, n-m? What I mean is the score can go, for example, 1-0 -> 2-0 -> 3-0 -> 3-1 -> 3-2 -> 3-3 ...that is, how many different combinations of a team scoring n goals while the other scores m goals?

Edit: To clarify, we distinguish scores like 2-1 and 1-2, i.e. the second score might be greater than the first to indicate that the away team is leading.

Comment: Do you distinguish between the teams?  In your example, would AAABBB and BBBAAA both make that score series, or would one be 0-1->0-2->0-3->1-3->2-3->3-3?  Would ABABAB and ABBABA both make 1-0->1-1->2-1->2-2->3-2->3-3?

Comment: @RossMillikan The question reads "While watching a fooball match, I write down the score each time a goal is scored to make a list.  Suppose that the match finishes with the score 3 all (i.e. each team has scored 3 goals).  How many different ways are there of reaching this scoreline (in other words how many different possibilities are there for the list I write down)?  Can you generalise to a match that finishes with a different score?", I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Reading this again, I am not totally sure how to interpret this, but, to be precise, let's distinguish the teams... what's the difference of we do or if we don't?

Comment: I gave some examples that should show the difference.  Frequently when people give sports scores they always give the leading score first if the teams are not tied.  That was the point of my second example.  If A scores first you give the score as 1-0.  If B then scores twice, most would give the score as 2-1  If you do that there are fewer possibilities than if you always give A first because you can never have 1-2.  You need to define the question clearly.

Comment: I see what you mean now, but what I had in mind are strict football score rules, where we allow 1-2 and such scores.

Comment: You should edit that into the question.  Then Will Jagy's answer is correct.  You have a line of $m+n$ goals scored and choose $m$ of them for team A to score.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93024/discussion-between-jbuck-and-ross-millikan).

Answer (score 1):

$$   \frac{(m+n)!}{m! \; \; \; n!}    $$

Comment: +1 for clean, justified in comment section by @Ross Millikan

Comment: @SakethMalyala we get lots of questions about the number of paths going from lower left to upper right on a square/rectangular lattice, where each step must be up one or to the right by one, while consecutive steps in the same direction are permitted

Comment: @WillJagy An internet research gave me ((n+k) choose k) different paths for a lattice. I suppose the result here is different because we only allow steps up (i.e. something like "home team scores" or right ("away team scores"), and not left or down. Is my intuition correct? This is the first time is see lattices in my life to be honest... also, do you mind elaborating on how do we get that number? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JBuck the other expression, ((n+k) choose n), is the same value as yours.

Comment: @ohhh right that was a brainfart... thank you!